# yarn error while creating react application

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

[while running create-react-app command on command prompt using yarn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zvf4S.png)

info "fsevents@2.1.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check.
Excluding it from installation.
error An unexpected error occurred: "EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:
\my-app\node_modules\@babel\compat-data\node_modules\.bin'".

```
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information p
rovided in "D:\\my-app\\yarn-error.log".

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this comm
and.

`yarnpkg add @testing-library/react@^9.3.2 @testing-library/jest-dom@^4.2.4 @tes
ting-library/user-event@^7.1.2` failed

D:\>
```

Comment: Run cmd as administrator

Comment: i faced issue using both yarn and npm while create react app

Comment: info fsevents@1.2.12: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module. what exactly this..?

Comment: You don't have to worry about fsevents warnings usually, did you try running cmd as admin?

Comment: yes sir.. I tried from cmd as administrator.. same issue occured

Comment: Post the full command prompt output, including the command you ran

Comment: i have added the command prompt post on above link please check

Comment: Why are you not using the latest `npx` command? https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a git repository for version control or publishing to a site like GitHub, you need to [install git](https://git-scm.com/) before running `create-react-app`. Otherwise, you can ignore it and use the app in your `samples` directory without git.